# Programatically change check box state in dialog box?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog with a series of checkboxes. The first one is 'Select All'; the others are user options.

How can I programatically change the state of the checkboxes so that when 'Select All' is checked, all the others are also checked, and when one of the others is selected, 'Select All' is unchecked? I can set up the initial state in the configuration, but can't work out how to change the checked state of the boxes on the fly.

Thanks.

Comment: you can set check on the onclickListener() in which you can put all the id  setChecked(true).

Comment: But the checkboxes are in an alertdialog so they don't have an id.

Answer (score 0):

> But the checkboxes are in an alertdialog so they don't have an id.

Whenever you inflate the custom layout for your alert dialog, you can get the references to the checkboxes via the `findViewById()` method.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
View customView = inflater.inflate(...);
CheckBox selectAll = customView.findViewById(R.id.select_all);
// attach listeners after this.
```

If you have a lot of complex processing to do, use a `DialogFragment` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogFragment and make your own Dialog Layouts.
Extend your activity with FragmentActivity
because getSupportFragmentManager()  only work with FragmentActivity

```
//dialog.setArguments(bundle);  if you want to pass values with bundle then use this
```

If you want to show dialof from FragmentActivity use :

```
 DialogFragment newFragment = H_Calendar_UserScheduleEditFragment
                .newInstance(b);
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

if you want to show it from fragment:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = H_Calendar_UserScheduleEditFragment
                .newInstance(b);

/** Getting callback from dialog fragment by set target fragment **/


    newFragment.setTargetFragment(H_UserCalanderFragment.this, 0);
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");




public class H_Calendar_UserScheduleEditFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Bundle b;


public static H_Calendar_UserScheduleEditFragment newInstance(Bundle b) {

    H_Calendar_UserScheduleEditFragment hschedule = new H_Calendar_UserScheduleEditFragment();
    hschedule.setArguments(b);

    return hschedule;
}

use this method if you want some callback in Activity:
Create your own listner and just pass Activity refrence or fragment refrence to to your listner refrence variable. And on completion or cancelation of dialog do whatever you want from your listner to do. 

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the
        // NoticeDialogListener
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
            try {

                Bundle notificationBundle = getArguments();

                // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the
                // host
                //this.mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
            }
        }

Use this if you want callback in Fragment:

    @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

            super.onAttach(activity);

            try {

                //this.mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) getTargetFragment();

            } catch (final ClassCastException e) {

                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//To make your dialg fragment to see on full screen , then incude this



getActivity().getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME;
    int theme = R.style.CustomizeDialog;
    // int theme = android.R.style.Theme_Wallpaper;
    setStyle(style, theme);
    b = getArguments();

}

include this style in your style.xml

    <style name="CustomizeDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        </style>


Now in oncreate view

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.my_schedule_calander_userupdatedelete, container,
                    false);

            FindId(v);
            SetListner();


            return v;
        }
```

///This is all the journey to create your own dialog from fragment or from Activity.
Now you have to implement logic of check selection
Take check boxes in  listview and one seperate at top. 
check if top check is selected select all checkbox of listview.

otherwise listen for checkseletion in listview.Try and let me know if there comes any problem

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a really complicated way to implement this though.

Comment: Nothing is compliated just use it and you will notice it was not.